# SharePoint 2013 - Metadata automatically removed after document is Viewed

Tags: 2013, metadata

We are using 2013. Recently one of the team sites, and only this specific one, has started having issues. When a user opens the document to read, no edit/checkout, then closes after any amount of time, the document loses its metadata, Group/Document Type/Etc.

Anyone have an idea as to why this may be occurring and or have possible solutions on how I can fix it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I have the answer, but it's good to eliminate possible causes in any case.

If you check in your metadata field, is it have a dependent column?  Is it possible that the Parent column is missing or the combination you wish to pick is not possible, because of a dependency 'rule'?  (This applies to lookup columns).

[image: pic]

Otherwise you might need to check in Term Store Management in the Site Collection Site Settings to see which metadata columns you are trying to pick values from.  Then check on your Document Library/List to see that you have a metadata column which is feeding off the Term Store.

Comment: Checked the Term Store Management section and all was ok. Its really strange..

We created a new library and copied all files across and the new library is working fine. So we're going to put this in the WT... Folder and re-look at it if it ever rears its ugly head again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the office file(s) have passwords on them? If so this is why they loose metadata.

related post i found on the topic https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe8adf33-6a0f-417c-85ed-7b6cb65cb613/password-protected-office-files-and-metadata-loss